# Can you leave Tokyo voluntarily?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

In King of Tokyo, you gain victory points for entering (and starting your turn in) Tokyo, but it's very painful to stay there - all of the other monsters are trying to kill you. Can you leave Tokyo voluntarily? If so, under what circumstances?

This came up because there's a demo video that shows players leaving voluntarily, but the rules don't seem to have anything about it; I don't see any way to leave Tokyo except by yielding after taking damage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**, you can only leave Tokyo as the immediate result of taking damage (from an attack) while in Tokyo.

The rules ([PDF](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/63033/king-of-tokyo-english-rules)) state (under "Becoming King of Tokyo"):

> If you are attacked while in Tokyo and you don't want to be there anymore ... you can yield to the Monster that attacked.

This is the only reference to leaving Tokyo in the rulebook, and the only opportunity to leave.

(It also makes sense thematically; monsters wouldn't just wander off, but would only leave if forced, and only long enough to lick their wounds before they dive straight back in.)

Comment: If you're attacked but don't take damage (e.g. you have Camouflage) you can leave Tokyo. If you take damage without being attacked (e.g. someone buys Oil Refinery) you can't leave Tokyo.