# Do wings allow me to leave Tokyo?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

When in Tokyo if I use Wings (Pay 2 energy to avoid damage until the end of the monster turn) to avoid damage can I still leave Tokyo and have the player that rolled the claw take my place?

Or do I need to actually take damage to be able to leave Tokyo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you leave Tokyo voluntarily?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12446/can-you-leave-tokyo-voluntarily)

Comment: Yes, per the "can I leave Tokyo voluntarily?" Question, you **must actually take damage**.

Comment: Not a duplicate since it has the opposite answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/63033/king-of-tokyo-english-rules) state (under "Becoming King of Tokyo"):

> If you are attacked while in Tokyo and you don't want to be there anymore ... you can yield to the Monster that attacked.

There's no mention of actually taking damage. You merely need to be attacked. According to the rules, if you are attacked, may cede Tokyo even if you avoid the damage using the Wings.

Comment: This is made a lot less clear by the text "If an attack somehow ends up doing no damage (due to camouflage for example), then it is no longer considered an attack for the purposes of cards like Poison Spit or Herbivore." A strict reading would say that only applies to card effects, but this exemption buried in the glossary does sow confusion as to whether a 0 damage attack counts as an attack in any circumstances.

Comment: @Weeble, What do those cards do? Poison Spit sounds like a damage augmenter, so it would make sense that it doesn't augment an attack that missed. On the other hand, it would make sense so use the wings to flee completely out of Tokyo. So you're right that it adds confusion, but it doesn't rule out my answer either. I guess the game maker would have to answer this one.

Comment: I agree, your answer makes sense thematically and I *think* it agrees with a strict reading of the rules. I just wanted to address a potential source of confusion.